# Sublime Text (3) plugin define new panel

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I see a lot of calls to this `show_panel` function with an `args` object like this:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"],
    "command": "show_panel",
    "args": {"panel": "find_in_files"}
}
```

I cannot find where the `show_panel` function is defined and am beginning to think that it is not exposed. Is it possible to define a new panel?

Comment: It's a bit old but as i am researching for my sublime i found your post... Do you mean a new tab? i do my git in a toggleable new tab if that helps

Comment: Hey @Erik255 I am actually referring to a panel like what pops up when you try to do a find. I know that I can pop up a singe-line prompt at the bottom but I wanted to be able to create a multiline form. Let me know if you come up with a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. 
In Sublime Text 2, basically what you need is:

1. Create an output panel: window.get_output_panel("paneltest"), this return a <sublime.View object>
2. Enable edition: <sublime.View object>.set_read_only(False)
3. Open buffer editor:  <sublime.View object>.begin_edit(), this return a <sublime.Edit object>
4. Write to view you want: <sublime.View object>.insert(edit, pt.size(), "Writing...")
5. Close buffer editor:  <sublime.View object>.end_edit()
6. Disable edition: <sublime.View object>.set_read_only(True)
7. Show your panel: window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "output.paneltest"})

To test, enter lines above one by one on Console View in Sublime:

```python
pt = window.get_output_panel("paneltest")
pt.set_read_only(False)
edit = pt.begin_edit()
pt.insert(edit, pt.size(), "Writing...")
pt.end_edit(edit)
window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "output.paneltest"})
```

In Sublime Text 3, don't execute steps 3 and 5.

Comment: That does answer my question. I guess then that leads me to wonder if that panel can be skinned and if buttons can be added to it or if we are limited to text and no interaction.

Comment: If you don't do steps 3 and 5 how do you write to the panel in step 4 without an edit variable?

Comment: Is there documentation for this sort thing in sublime ?

Comment: @Jon In ST3, you are supposed to create a TextCommand that does the editing and then run the command on the panel (which is a view). See https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html